# apache server takes too much time to resize a image

Tags: apache2

i have a lamp server which runs php script. i use this script https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/example/upload.php which automatically uploads and resize the image to the defined resolution.

i have a problem now. a 5Mb file takes about 6 seconds to finish the full job. if i queue up 10 files for upload  the server is not responding for other requests. and the both cores of the processor are at 100% use.

i have the full access to the server. what should i do to reduce the work load of the server. is the problem on the scripts or should i use any pluggins for resizing..

Comment: I think this has much better chances to be answered at stackoverflow or serverfault

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP file you linked uses the `imagecopyresampled` function, which needs much cpu to do the work. You can use the function `imagecopyresized` instead, but the resulting quality will be worse then.

Depending on the destination size, you can combine these two, first reduce the pictures size by `imagecopyresized` half of its size, and use then `imagecopyresampled` to reduce the size to its final size. This should end in a similar quality as if you would have done it in one step using `imagecopyresampled`